# How to securely save the redux-persist-transform-encrypt key?

Tags: react-native, security, redux, redux-persist

i am trying to persist and encrypt the redux store my react-native app.

i am trying to use [redux-persist-transform-encrypt](https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt) as per the documentation:

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt'

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: 'my-super-secret-key'
})

const reducer = persistReducer(
  {
    transforms: [encryptor]
  },
  baseReducer
)
```

but the big deal is to find a secure way to store 'my-super-secret-key'.
I've successfully got it from user input and saved it with [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain).
Now the problem is that the function to get the key from the keychain is asynchronous and i would need to get the key before the store initialisation.

The result would look like this

```
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt'

const encryptionKey = // get the key here from the keychain before initiating the store

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: encryptionKey
})

const reducer = persistReducer(
  {
    transforms: [encryptor]
  },
  baseReducer
)
```

Do someone have any workaround for me?

Answer (score 1):

I also spent some time how to resolve this. At first I found nice library to save generated secret key into keychain called `react-native-sensitive-info`. After that I was facing the problem that getting and setting generated secret key is asynchronous. Then I figured out that AsyncStorage is used as a storage in the config for `persistReducer` and there was the way - let's create a storage which uses `react-native-sensitive-info`. After a while, I stumbled upon a library that already exists and is implementing exactly the same logic. This is it -> [`redux-persist-sensitive-storage`](https://github.com/CodingZeal/redux-persist-sensitive-storage).

Just use it like this:

```js
...
import createSensitiveStorage from 'redux-persist-sensitive-storage';

const appReducer = combineReducers(myReducers);

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: createSensitiveStorage({
    keychainService: 'myKeychain',
    sharedPreferencesName: 'mySharedPrefs'
  })
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, appReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
...
```

That's it!